# record matching/similarity calculation for numbers and characters

Tags: r, duplicates, matching, similarity, record-linkage

I have a dataframe structured the following way with much more rows and columns:

| Report_ID | Block_ID | Number | Character |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | A |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | A |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | B |
| 4 | 2 | 10 | A |
| 5 | 2 | 11 | B |
| 6 | 2 | 100 | C |
| 7 | 3 | 2 | D |
| 8 | 3 | #NA | A |
| 9 | 3 | 8 | D |
| 10 | 3 | 2 | A |

[df structure for possible matches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2Ds9.png)

and I would like to compare the records per Block-ID and calculate the similarity per each combination of Report-IDs.

A result df could look like this:

| Report_ID_combination | Similarity_Number | Similarity_Character |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1_2 | 0.60 | 1 |
| 1_3 | 0.40 | 0 |
| 4_5 | 0.91 | 0 |
| 4_6 | 0.10 | 0 |
| 7_8 | NA | 0 |
| 7_9 | 0.25 | 1 |
| 7_10 | 1.00 | 0 |

[df structure for similarity calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7vsu.png)

Calculations for similarity: 
Similarity_Number = lower value of number divided by higher value of number per  report_ID_combination 
Similarity_Character = if character in first report matches the character in second report, return 1, elso 0.
If one of the 2 reports is reported with NA for an attribute, the similarity for this attribute is also NA.

So, I'm not looking for any edit distance, Jaccard similarity or something like this, but a package in R where the similarity is calculated blockwise and where I can manually adjust the calculation of similarity (maybe change to absolute calculation for numbers or take into account NA values). 
As far as I know
`RecordLinkage`
comes only with 0/1 similarity calculation for comparisons between numbers.

Thanks,
Marius

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly into a [code block].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible approach:

(Assumes all possible combinations are required within the block, e.g. `2_3` in addition to `1_2` and `1_3`.)

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~"Report_ID", ~"Block_IDm", ~"Number", ~"Character",
  1, 1, 5, "A",
  2, 1, 3, "A",
  3, 1, 2, "B",
  4, 2, 10, "A",
  5, 2, 11, "B",
  6, 2, 100, "C",
  7, 3, 2, "D",
  8, 3, NA, "A",
  9, 3, 8, "D",
  10, 3, 2, "A"
)

combos <- df |>
  split(df$Block_IDm) |>
  map(\(df) combn(df$Report_ID, 2) |>
    t() |>
    as_tibble()) |>
  bind_rows()

map2(combos$V1, combos$V2, \(x, y){
  df |>
    filter(Report_ID == x | Report_ID == y) |>
    summarise(
      Report_ID_combination = str_c(Report_ID, collapse = "_"),
      Similarity_Number = min(Number) / max(Number),
      Similarity_Character = if_else(first(Character) == last(Character), 1, 0)
    )
}) |>
  bind_rows()
#> # A tibble: 12 × 3
#>    Report_ID_combination Similarity_Number Similarity_Character
#>    <chr>                             <dbl>                <dbl>
#>  1 1_2                               0.6                      1
#>  2 1_3                               0.4                      0
#>  3 2_3                               0.667                    0
#>  4 4_5                               0.909                    0
#>  5 4_6                               0.1                      0
#>  6 5_6                               0.11                     0
#>  7 7_8                              NA                        0
#>  8 7_9                               0.25                     1
#>  9 7_10                              1                        0
#> 10 8_9                              NA                        0
#> 11 8_10                             NA                        1
#> 12 9_10                              0.25                     0
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-06 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>